# 'may be' or 'might be'?

Tags: grammaticality

If I share my teacher's instructions with a friend from another class do I say
"It may be different for different classes though" or "It might be different for...".

Is there a way to know which one to use when?

Comment: *Might* fits the future and you are making a prediction.

Comment: Either is fine.

Comment: For many speakers (especially younger ones) ,"might" is no longer the preterite of "may", but a distinct lexeme that is largely interchangeable with "may".

Comment: He may come. There is the possibility he will come. He might come, The possibility is not as strong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct. You can use either.

**May** and **might** are used to talk about possible actions or happenings. They  mean the same. It doesn't matter whether we use 'may' or 'might'.

He may be going to London.= He might be going to London.

She may be able to give you some money.= She might be able to give you some money.

[Some people think that 'might' is used to talk about a smaller chance than 'may'.]